# How can I programmatically delete a python launching executable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a program delete its own executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606140/can-a-program-delete-its-own-executable)

My application is compiled in Py2exe. However after execution is finished, another application will be loaded. The main executable will no longer be needed, so how can I go about having the Python application delete itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you control the second executable's source code, you can delete the first executable from the second. Other than that, I can't think of a way to accomplish this.