# Auto deleting exe on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-xp

I found this code on the Internet but it says that is to be run on Windows XP.
I tried to run it on Windows 7 and it worked, but I wonder if it is safe, not just running this code, but also doing it on Windows 7.

```
//
//  Self-deleting exe under Windows XP
//
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// get this right!
#define EXPLORER_PID 1444

typedef UINT  (WINAPI * WAIT_PROC)(HANDLE, DWORD);  // WaitForSingleObject
typedef BOOL  (WINAPI * CLOSE_PROC)(HANDLE);        // CloseHandle
typedef BOOL  (WINAPI * DELETE_PROC)(LPCTSTR);      // DeleteFile
typedef VOID  (WINAPI * EXIT_PROC)(DWORD);          // ExitProcess

typedef struct
{
    WAIT_PROC   fnWaitForSingleObject;
    CLOSE_PROC  fnCloseHandle;
    DELETE_PROC fnDeleteFile;
    EXIT_PROC   fnExitProcess;

    HANDLE      hProcess;
    TCHAR       szFileName[MAX_PATH];

} INJECT;

#pragma optimize("gsy", off)
#pragma check_stack(off)        // doesn't work :-(

DWORD WINAPI RemoteThread(INJECT *remote)
{
    remote->fnWaitForSingleObject(remote->hProcess, INFINITE);
    remote->fnCloseHandle(remote->hProcess);
    remote->fnDeleteFile(remote->szFileName);
    remote->fnExitProcess(0);

    return 0;
}

#pragma check_stack

HANDLE GetRemoteProcess()
{
    STARTUPINFO         si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    //return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, EXPLORER_PID);

    if(CreateProcess(0, "explorer.exe", 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED|CREATE_NO_WINDOW|IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        return pi.hProcess;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

PVOID GetFunctionAddr(PVOID func)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG

    // get address of function from the JMP <relative> instruction
    DWORD *offset = (BYTE *)func + 1;
    return (PVOID)(*offset + (BYTE *)func + 5);

#else

    return func;

#endif
}

BOOL SelfDelete()
{
    INJECT local, *remote;
    BYTE   *code;
    HMODULE hKernel32;
    HANDLE  hRemoteProcess;
    HANDLE  hCurProc;

    DWORD   dwThreadId;
    HANDLE  hThread = 0;

    char ach[80];

    hRemoteProcess = GetRemoteProcess();

    if(hRemoteProcess == 0)
        return FALSE;

    // Allocate memory in remote process
    code = VirtualAllocEx(hRemoteProcess, 0, sizeof(INJECT) + 128, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if(code == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(hRemoteProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }

    hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle(_T("kernel32.dll"));

    // setup remote structure
    remote = (INJECT *)(code + 128);

    local.fnWaitForSingleObject  = (WAIT_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32,  "WaitForSingleObject");
    local.fnCloseHandle          = (CLOSE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "CloseHandle");
    local.fnExitProcess          = (EXIT_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "ExitProcess");

#ifdef UNICODE
    local.fnDeleteFile            = (DELETE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "DeleteFileW");
#else
    local.fnDeleteFile            = (DELETE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "DeleteFileA");
#endif

    // duplicate our own process handle for remote process to wait on
    hCurProc = GetCurrentProcess();
    DuplicateHandle(hCurProc, hCurProc, hRemoteProcess, &local.hProcess, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    // find name of current executable
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, local.szFileName, MAX_PATH);

    // write in code to execute, and the remote structure
    WriteProcessMemory(hRemoteProcess, code,    GetFunctionAddr(RemoteThread), 128, 0);
    WriteProcessMemory(hRemoteProcess, remote, &local, sizeof(local), 0);

    wsprintf(ach, "%x %x\n", code, remote);
    OutputDebugString(ach);

    // execute the code in remote process
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hRemoteProcess, 0, 0, code, remote, 0, &dwThreadId);

    if(hThread != 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main(void)
{
    SelfDelete();

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, how could this be used as a library in C/C++? 
My goal is to just use, for example,

`#include "selfdel.h"` so I can use just the function `SelfDelete()` in a C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

You should realize what this code is. It's an injection of a code into another process which will be executed as that process and then the process will exit. It should just work (though look at the comments below). I think the author of this code snippet had written it before Win Vista was released, therefore the concern you have.

You can declare `SelfDelete()` in your "selfdel.h". Calling this function and exiting right away should do the trick.

The implementation doesn't require any input from user of the library since it gets everything it needs.

```
// duplicate our own process handle for remote process to wait on
hCurProc = GetCurrentProcess();
...
// find name of current executable
GetModuleFileName(NULL, local.szFileName, MAX_PATH);
```

Some comments:

- Your process should have enough rights to create the other one
- Such activity may be treated as suspicious by anti-virus software
- Don't forget that "zombie" process will wait as long as your process lives after calling `SelfDelete()`
- Consider other approaches: [How can a program delete its own executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606140/how-can-a-program-delete-its-own-executable)

Comment: I tried this but it won't work: #ifndef SELFDELETE_H_
    #define SELFDELETE_H_

    BOOL SelfDelete();

    #endif // SELFDELETE_H_

Comment: Are you saying the code works as it is, but when you include it to another project it stops working? I have tried it and it works fine for me on Win10 + MSVC 2015. The only problem is that 'SelfDelete()' crashes "explorer.exe" (or any other) if you compile it with /RTCs (which is enabled if you compile it as debug). Perhaps this is why you put `#pragma check_stack(off)        // doesn't work :-(` ?