# Delphi - improve my code to self delete executable

Tags: delphi, batch-file, delphi-7, self-destruction

I always worked with this code to self-delete my executable. But I think that's a ridicule way to do it. What can I do to improve this? I guess using a external Batch isn't even correct. Code Below:

```
  procedure SelfDelete;
   var
   myFile : TextFile;
   begin
     AssignFile(myFile, 'C:\Test.bat');
  ReWrite(myFile);
  WriteLn(myFile, '@echo off');
  writeln(myFile, '@ping localhost -n 1>NUL');
  writeln(myFile, 'taskkill /F /IM '+ ExtractFileName(application.exename));
  writeln(myFIle, 'del /s /q "'+Application.Exename+'"');
    writeln(myFile, 'del /s /q "%~f0"');
  CloseFile(myFile);
   end;
```

and OnClose Event I did.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
WinExec('C:\Test.bat',0);
end;
```

Somebody can help made it to show less moron? Thanks

Comment: I would [follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606189/8041231).

Comment: It does basically the same thing as my. But I don't know if I trust in del *.* . That would delete everything in a folder...

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read it carefully, only if _lpExistingFileName refers to a directory, the system removes the directory at restart only if the directory is empty_. If it refers to a file, it deletes a file.

Comment: In most cases, this will work:
<code> 
if fileexists('project1.exe') then
  begin
    renamefile('project1.exe','fred');
    deletefile('fred');
  end;
</code>