# Start external application from Python as new process

Tags: python-3.x, run-app

How to start an external application with python but not using os.system or subprocess.call?
This external application is one another Win32 console app.
The problem with os.system('app') is that when executed external app is closed then I can continue with the rest of application, and with subprocess.call the output of that external app is inside python process.

```
import os
import subprocess

def runapp():
    os.system(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"')
    anotherfunction()

def anotherfunction():
    # do something
```

In given example above when I close Word then anotherfunction() is called. Is there any other way to run external app?

Answer (score 2):

I had found solution:

```
os.startfile(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE"')
```